# Retag etiquette?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The question [In Strongly connected tournament T.Is it NP-hard to find a minimum number of vertices(V1) which make T\V1 as non strongly connected tournament.](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/942/in-strongly-connected-tournament-t-is-it-np-hard-to-find-a-minimum-number-of-vert) was retagged twice, from the original "np" to add tags "graph-theory" (which makes sense) and "ds.data-structures" (which doesn't, at least to me).  After checking the FAQ for MO about Community Wiki mode it seems retagging does not count to make a post into a community wiki, so I retagged it yet again.

My retag removes one of the tags that was added in a previous retag.

> What should the etiquette be for retagging?

I would normally explain my decision to roll back or modify a previous edit.  However, retagging doesn't request an edit comment, so even access to version control tools would not help much here.  It would be nice not to have retag wars, but a meta question for every retag conflict seems too much overhead.

Moreover, if I remember correctly, some MO members were upset when Suresh retagged some old posts, causing them to be bumped onto the front page.  Is this reasonable?

Comment: I thought that we had some kind of consensus that there should be at least one "ArXiv tag" in each question. DS in ArXiv = data structures and *algorithms*, and that's why I thought the DS tag would make sense here. Alternatively or additionally, you could also add the CC tag.

Comment: Yes, there should be at least one arxiv tag, and it doesn't hurt to have multiple arxiv tags. If you really think something is very poorly tagged, then it makes sense to flag it. Jukka is right that DS actually means "data structures and algorithms". (There is also some moderator feature that will let us declare multiple tags as "synonyms". We're still figuring that one out.)

Comment: And as a reminder, here is the proposal regarding renaming the arxiv tags: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/118/proposal-remove-discipline-prefix-from-the-arxiv-style-tags/132#132 (one of the points is to rename cs.ds.data-structures -> ds.algorithms to avoid exactly this confusion).

Comment: some background: I've already renamed cs.cc.complexity-theory as cc.complexity-theory and have set up the synonym. the problem is that the retagging still promotes at least one post to the front (when I create a new tag). Merging tags doesn't though. I did a quick check on meta.SO, and this is the expected behavior, so I'll go ahead and change some more tags over - mainly the arxiv ones as per the proposal. 

Is there a proposal here to rename algorithms also to ds.data-structures ?

Comment: p.s i know someone did a spate of retagging that caused trouble on meta.MO , but I didn't see any complaints about mine !

Comment: Apologies, missed the consensus about always having an arXiv tag.  Please add back the tag if you wish!

Comment: Maybe add the decision about arxiv-style tags to the FAQ?